# Replacing characters in a string using replace()

Tags: javascript, shopify

I wrote this js to pull values from select statements to build a link that the user will be sent to. The problem is that I am using this with Shopify where the products are stored under

```
/products/handle
```

and Shopify uses '-' to replace '.' in links.

I have tried many different ways of using the replace function using it for a single instance of the character, storing the new value in a differently named variable, and trying to perform the replace when building the link.

```
myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var val1 = document.getElementById("shortSide").value;
    var val2 = document.getElementById("longSide").value;
    var val3 = document.getElementById("widthSide").value;
    var hyph = '-';
    if(val1 != "default" && val2 != "default" && val2 != "Long Side" && val3 != "default" && val3 != "Width")
      window.location.href = "/products/" + val1.replace(/\./g,hyph) + "x" + val2.replace(/\./g,hyph) + "x" + val3;
    else
        alert("Fill out everything please!");
}, false)
```

If the variables contain

```
var1 = '16.88'
var2 = '25.25'
var3 = '1'
```

The expected output would be

```
/products/16-88x25-25x1
```

but the actual output is

```
/products/16.88x25.25x1
```

Comment: I have updated the code to include the backslash but it still does not work. The statement doesn't work even when not using regex ie ('.' , hyph)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.` is a special character in regex (It will match any character except line terminators), you need to escape it with a backslash:

```
val1.replace(/\./g,hyph)
```

E.g.

```js
var hyph = '-'
var val1 = '16.88'
var val2 = '25.25'
var val3 = '1'

console.log("/products/" + val1.replace(/\./g,hyph) + "x" + val2.replace(/\./g,hyph) + "x" + val3)
```

Comment: I have updated my question to include the proper regex but the output is still not replacing the characters.

Comment: @ZachHolmes I've added a functioning example to the answer, the code should work. If you're not seeing the right output then perhaps the code isn't actually being run. Have you tried stepping through it in a debug console?

Comment: The script is running because I am getting output just not the correct one. I think that the problem is with Shopify because running the script locally does produce the desired output. Your answer is correct though.

Comment: The code is working properly on Shopify. I think it might have been something to do with their internal caching because even accessing the website from another computer/browser/cleared cache didn't work and out of nowhere it just started working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for solving your problem. `.` means a character. For catching dot you have to do something like `\.`;

```js
var1 = '16.88'
var2 = '25.25'
var3 = '1';

let href = "/products/" + var1.replace(/\./g, '-') + 'x' + var2.replace(/\./g, '-') + 'x' + var3.replace(/\./g, '-');


console.log(href);
```